# Why there is space around the text in the HTML?

Tags: html, css, dom

In the html I have below code. Text without the span element is getting space around it. But Text with the span element is not getting the space aournd it. Why there is space around the text, but not with span. This might be some behavior, I am new to this one. I searched in google but didn't get articles related to this behavior

```html
Sample Text
<span>Sample Text</span>
```

[image]

Comment: Because there *is* space between `<body>` and the text and the text and the next `<span>`, but there's no space within the `<span>`…!?

Comment: this happens on chrome only, it's a browser styling.

Comment: No @Raymond that is a different answer. But deceze's comment is giving the good explanation. Thanks deceze

Comment: @JavascriptLover-SKT kind of related, chrome use "" to represent a raw string with style. you don't see this on IE though, it's a chrome thing

Answer (score 0):

Text without span element is getting space because of the body.

span is an inline tag it takes space as much as required and leaves space for other element.

below example all four-span element will display in the same line because each tag takes only necessary space and rest of space free for other elements.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
   <head> 
      <title>Test span tag</title> 
   </head> 
   <body> 
      <h2>Welcome To stackoverflow</h2> 
       <!-- span tags with inline style/css  -->    
      <span style="background-color:powderblue;"> 
       Stack</span> 
      <span style="background-color: lightgray;"> 
      -Contribute-</span> 
      <span style="background-color: yellow;"> 
      Article</span> 
      <span style="background-color: lightgreen;"> 
      STCK</span> 
   </body> 
</html>
```